# Updating my dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

This should be a simple problem but I just can't wrap my head around it. I have a dictionary called `TD`. The {key1{key2:values}} of `TD` are `{1:{u'word':3, u'next':2, u'the':2},2:{...}...}` where `key1` is a document,`key2` is a word in a document and `value` is the number of times that word appears in the document, obtained using the `Counter` method.

I have a large number of documents so each document has an entry in TD:

```
TD = {1:{u'word':2, u'next':1, u'the':5,...},
      2:{u'my':4, u'you':1, u'other':2,...},
      ...
      168:{u'word':1, u'person':1, u'and':8,...}}
```

What I now want to do is check each word in `{1{...}}` to see if it appears in the other documents and repeat this process for each document. For each document a word appears in, `freq` is increased by 1. I have a new dictionary called `Score` that should look like this:

```
{1:{u'word':score, u'next':score,...}, 2:{u'my':score, u'you':score,...}...}
```

To obtain this dictionary:

```
Score={}
count = 0
for x,i in TD[count].iteritems():
    freq=1
    num=1
    for y in TD[num].keys():
        if word in TF[num].keys():
            freq+=1
        num+=1
    Score[num]={x:(i*freq)}
    num+=1
```

This is giving me the following output:

```
{1:{u'word':score}, 2:{u'next':score}, 3:{u'the':score}...}
```

should be:

```
{1:{u'word':score, u'next':score, u'the':score,...}...}
```

I think the problem is with the line `Score[num]={x:(i*freq)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dict views](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to find the intersection between documents, then a Counter to count their frequencies:

```
Score = {}
for id, document in TD.iteritems():
    counts = Score[id] = Counter()
    for otherid, otherdocument in TD.iteritems():
        if otherid == id:
            continue  # Skip current document
        counts.update(document.viewkeys() & otherdocument.viewkeys())
```

Each entry in Score will be a count of how often each word in a document appears in the other documents.

If you need to include the word count in the current document as well (count + 1), simply remove the `if otherid == id` test.

In your own code you confused `num` and `count`, but in python you *usually* don't need to manually increment a loop counter in any case.

Comment: This won't work because I need the word too. If I did it that way it would be `{u'word':score}` but I need it to be `{1:{u'word':score, u'next':score,...},2{...}...}`

Comment: Updated; using [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) and an inner loop to count word frequencies across the documents.

Comment: still not what I am trying to do. I just need to see if the word appears in the other documents, doesn't matter how often. My original dictionary `TD` contains the word count for each document. The new dict stores the value of TD*the number of docs the word appears in

Comment: @adohertyd: That's *exactly* what my code does. It counts how many documents each word in a given document appears in. Try it out. :-)

Comment: Sorry you are right I thought it was counting how many times each word appears across the documents. Thanks for that!